# How we can change the Font Size and Font Family of a DataGrid dynamically?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have a Flex Screen `MyData.mxml` which has a table of values using a DataGrid. All the styles of the DataGrid are included in a `default.css` file that is part of a Flex Library Project. This will be converted in an swc file and used in the Flex project where i use `MyData.mxml`.

In MyData screen, we have an option to change the Font size of the DataGrid. We have a RadioButtonGroup where the user can choose from  two option buttons:

- Normal Font (Verdana, 12)
- Small Font (Verdana, 11)

When the user chooses the 'Normal Font' button, all the data in the DataGrid should be set to Verdana 12 and when the user choose the Small Font option button, all the data in the DataGrid should be set to Verdana 11.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the following code can solve your problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application layout="vertical" verticalAlign="middle" xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public static const NORMAL_STYLE:String = "normal";
        public static const SMALL_STYLE:String = "small";

        protected function styleGroup_changeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            var fontFamily:String = "Verdana";
            var fontSize:int;
            switch (styleGroup.selectedValue)
            {
                case NORMAL_STYLE:
                    fontSize = 12;
                    break;
                case SMALL_STYLE:
                    fontSize = 11;
                    break;
            }
            dataGrid.setStyle("fontFamily", fontFamily);
            dataGrid.setStyle("fontSize", fontSize);
        }
    ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:ArrayCollection id="dataGridData">
        <mx:source>
            <mx:Array>
                <mx:Object first="First1" second="Second1" />
                <mx:Object first="First2" second="Second2" />
            </mx:Array>
        </mx:source>
    </mx:ArrayCollection>

    <mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{dataGridData}" height="200" id="dataGrid">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="first" headerText="First" />
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="second" headerText="Second" />
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
    <mx:RadioButtonGroup change="styleGroup_changeHandler(event)" id="styleGroup" />
    <mx:RadioButton group="{styleGroup}" label="Normal" value="{NORMAL_STYLE}" />
    <mx:RadioButton group="{styleGroup}" label="Small" value="{SMALL_STYLE}" />
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Hai friend, thanks for your kind response! I've tried what you've suggested, and it's working fine. But, I was asked to get the style name from the css file. So, I've added two style components in the css file like the following: '.dataGridNormal' and '.dataGridSmall' and called them in the respective conditional block in the main mxml. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: I'm glad that my solution helped you to solve your problem :)